# How to use IsText with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am learning VBA and am trying to execute the code:

```
Sub example()

    If IsText(ActiveCell) Then

       MsgBox "Is Text"

    Else: MsgBox "Not Text"

    End If

End Sub
```

It does not work, and gives me the error, "Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined" with the "IsText" highlighted. The macro works fine if I exchange "IsText" for "IsNumeric". Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IsText is a worksheet function. Use worksheetfunction to apply it within vba.

```
If worksheetfunction.IsText(ActiveCell) Then
```

Comment: Thanks so much! As I said, I'm just starting to learn, so didn't even know there was such a thing as a worksheet function. But it makes sense now. Though I'm not sure why there would be a worksheet function that isn't automatically defined as well in the VBA/Macro universe. But that's a question for another day.

Comment: Another example might be the ISNUMBER worksheet function that is called IsNumeric in vba or the IsDate function that is native to vba but has no equivalent on the worksheet.